# Calling an android app stored on a server from another android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android app that requires calling some other android apps that are stored on a remote server.What i basically want to do is that when i want to run an android app from my parent app it should be downloaded from the server an run and upon exiting from the downloaded app it must be deleted.Is there a way to do this??

Comment: Yes, but it'll go through the normal installation procedures... and also I don't think you can guarantee deletion. That is.. unless that app deletes itself.

Comment: Android apps don't run on servers. So, no.

Comment: @323go - please read the question.  It was never stated that the app would *run* on the server (though that actually is possible), only that it would be *stored* there.

Comment: As for the question itself, the proposed installation scheme is probably not workable.  However, it's fairly straightforward to download and run *within an existing application* additional software modules if they are native libraries, and its extremely common to do so with code which runs in some interpreted language such as javascript within a webview.  It's thought possible to do it with with Dalvik code compiled from Java as well, but likely much more tricky.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanx chris!!can u please provide me some source from where i can study more about it?

Comment: @ChrisStratton  and also u said that it is possible to run an app on a server.can u please tell me how to do that?

Comment: @user2586942 - you'll need to decide what approach best fits your goal and then do some research on it.  As for running an app on a server, it's not very clear what the point would be, but it you can do it in an emulator or by building Android for the server's architecture; the only reason for doing it that immediately comes to mind is if you wanted to use a more powerful remote machine to host an emulator, or to test an app just built on a remote build server, on the same server.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, the title is grossly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

No.

First, while you can download an application and request for it to be installed, the user must agree to install it.

Second, while you can request that an app be uninstalled, the user must agree to uninstall it.